# How to let struct hold a thread and destroy thread as soon as it go out of scope

Tags: rust

```rust
struct ThreadHolder{
  state: ???
  thread: ???
}

impl ThreadHolder {
  fn launch(&mut self) {
    self.thread = ???
    // in thread change self.state
  }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
  let mut th = ThreadHolder{...};
  th.launch();
  // thread will be destroy as soon as th go out of scope
}
```

I think there is something to deal with lifetime, but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: [https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.0-alpha.6/tokio/timer/index.html](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.0-alpha.6/tokio/timer/index.html)?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios trying to implement `you draw I guess` game server side, where every room have a timer to count down painter remain paint time

Comment: Oh, you want a tick system, so that everybody uses the same "game time"? You should elaborate on that in your question because as is, it is not super clear.

Comment: just a small piece of feature, don't want whole `tokio` thing, maybe I will eventually use it after I lose my patient

Comment: Sounds like you just want an atomic integer to use across threads? Btw, if your C++ program was not using one, your C++ program was wrong.

Comment: @mcarton the tricky thing is to modify value in the `&mut self`, normal spawn need static lifetime. c++ with mutex or something is wayyyy straightforward to me than Rust, lifetime thing is really tricky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it work

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread::{sleep, spawn, JoinHandle};
use std::time::Duration;

struct Timer {
    pub(crate) time: Arc<Mutex<u32>>,
    jh_ticker: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl Timer {
    fn new<T>(i: T, duration: Duration) -> Self
    where
        T: Iterator<Item = u32> + Send + 'static,
    {
        let time = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

        let arc_time = time.clone();
        let jh_ticker = Some(spawn(move || {
            for item in i {
                let mut mg = arc_time.lock().unwrap();
                *mg = item;
                drop(mg); // needed, otherwise this thread will always hold lock
                sleep(duration);
            }
        }));

        Timer { time, jh_ticker }
    }
}

impl Drop for Timer {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.jh_ticker.take().unwrap().join();
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_timer() {
    let t = Timer::new(0..=10, Duration::from_secs(1));
    let a = t.time.clone();
    for _ in 0..100 {
        let b = *a.lock().unwrap();
        println!("{}", b);
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is so simple that you don't even need it to be mutable in any way, and then it becomes trivial to share it across threads, unless you want to reset it. You said you need to leave a thread, for one reason or another, therefore I'll assume that you don't care about this.

You instead can poll it every tick (most games run in ticks so I don't think there will be any issue implementing that).

I will provide example that uses sleep, so it's not most accurate thing, it is painfully obvious on the last subsecond duration, but I am not trying to do your work for you anyway, there's enough resources on internet that can help you deal with it.

Here it goes:

```rust
use std::{
    sync::Arc,
    thread::{self, Result},
    time::{Duration, Instant},
};

struct Timer {
    end: Instant,
}

impl Timer {
    fn new(duration: Duration) -> Self {
        // this code is valid for now, but might break in the future
        // future so distant, that you really don't need to care unless
        // you let your players draw for eternity
        let end = Instant::now().checked_add(duration).unwrap();

        Timer { end }
    }

    fn left(&self) -> Duration {
        self.end.saturating_duration_since(Instant::now())
    }

    // more usable than above with fractional value being accounted for
    fn secs_left(&self) -> u64 {
        let span = self.left();

        span.as_secs() + if span.subsec_millis() > 0 { 1 } else { 0 }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let timer = Timer::new(Duration::from_secs(10));
    let timer_main = Arc::new(timer);

    let timer = timer_main.clone();
    let t = thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let seconds_left = timer.secs_left();
        println!("[Worker] Seconds left: {}", seconds_left);

        if seconds_left == 0 {
            break;
        }

        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    });

    loop {
        let seconds_left = timer_main.secs_left();
        println!("[Main] Seconds left: {}", seconds_left);

        if seconds_left == 5 {
            println!("[Main] 5 seconds left, waiting for worker thread to finish work.");
            break;
        }

        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    }

    t.join()?;

    println!("[Main] worker thread finished work, shutting down!");

    Ok(())
}
```

By the way, this kind of implementation wouldn't be any different in any other language, so please don't blame Rust for it. It's not the easiest language, but it provides more than enough tools to build anything you want from scratch as long as you put effort into it.

Goodluck :)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your advice, but because that ` it has several rooms, each room have a timer to count down`, I need multiple Timer(Ticker) each have their own state, so I think it is a good idea to let each Timer instance have their own thread to take care itself, but I think your idea is feasible, each Timer only have their own state, there will be a dedicated thread to mutate them all